# Morris chart error when passing JSON data from PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, morris.js

I have data from a database that I put through `json_encode` with the following code:

```
$orderList = $this->Retrieve->retrieve_data('*');
$data = array();
foreach ($orderList as $order) {
    array_push($data, array(
        'd'     => $order['createdDate'],
        'sales' => $order['order_price']
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

This is the output:

```
{"data":[{"d":"2015-09-26","sales":"0.00"},{"d":"2015-09-26","sales":"200.00"},{"d":"2015-09-26","sales":"45.00"},{"d":"2015-09-26","sales":"1500.00"}]}
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + '/Memberinfo/getGraphicalActivity',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {patientFK: $("#patientFK").val()},
    dataType: "json",
    timeout:3000,
    success : function (data) {
        memberArea = new Morris.Line({
        element: 'line-chart-memberInfo',
        data: data,
        xkey: 'd',
        ykeys: ['sales'],
        labels: ['Sales'],
        smooth: false,
        parseTime:false,
        resize: true
        });
    },
    error : function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error " + errorThrown);
        if(textStatus==='timeout')
            alert("request timed out");
    }
});
```

It returns this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in how I was building my JSON data in PHP. Here's the code:

```
foreach ($orderList as $order) {
    $arr[] = array(
        'd'     => ''.$order['createdDate'].'',
        'sales' => ''.$order['order_price'].'',
    );
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```